# email missing from Google OAuth 2.0 ID token

Tags: google-oauth

This is largely a reboot of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778081/response-from-google-oauth-2-0-for-login-missing-email-after-authorization) unanswered question. We allow Google Sign-In to our site and, for the most part, it works well. But everyday a small fraction of the ID tokens we obtain from Google after authentication (between, say, 1 and 5% of them) do not contain an email, even though we specify "email" scope during front-end authentication. It's not consistent from user to user, and we are not able to reliably reproduce it (even though it consistently happens at the frequency above).

Has any encountered similar behavior?